# maximum value of the expression $x^4y^2+y^4z^2+z^4t^2+t^4x^2+2016x^4y^4z^4t^4$

Tags: inequality

> For $x, y, z, t$ non-negative real number find the maximum value of the expression $$x^4y^2+y^4z^2+z^4t^2+t^4x^2+2016x^4y^4z^4t^4$$ given that $x+y+z+t =1$

By Holder's:$$(x+y+z+t)^4(x+y+z+t)^2(1+1+1+1)^{-5} \ge 1\cdot x^4y^2+1\cdot y^4z^2+1\cdot z^4t^2+1\cdot t^4x^2 \\ \Rightarrow 4^{-5} \ge x^4y^2+y^4z^2+z^4t^2+t^4x^2 \qquad (1)$$

By AM-GM:$$\dfrac{x+y+z+t}{4} \ge (xyzt)^{\frac14} \\ \Rightarrow 2016\cdot 4^{-16} \ge 2016\cdot (xyzt)^4 \qquad (2)$$

By adding (1) and (2) we get $4^{-5}+2016\cdot 4^{-16}$ as the maximum value of the expression but it doesn't seem to be correct.

Comment: You are not asked to find some upper bound. You aupposed to find the maximum value. This is more restrictive. Holder' and AM-GM just give upper bounds, not the maximum. To find the maximum, differentiate.

Comment: @PaulSinclair The inequalities, appropriately used can give maximum, one has to ensure equally is possible as well to get the maximum.

Comment: You have used negative exponents in Holder, so that's not valid. Are you sure the variables are positive and not just non-negative? In strictly positive case, there is no maximum, only a supremem here.

Comment: sorry my bad... the variables are non-negative

Comment: @Macavity - appropriately used, indeed. However this particular apllication need not include the conditions where Holders or AM-GM take on their maximum.

Comment: when x=y=0, M=(4/27)^2≒0.2